# Finding the size of a char array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm making a calculator and I have converted a String to a char array using

```
char[] b = inputString.toCharArray();
```

(inputString is my String variable)

Because the String is an input I don't know how large the array will be. Is there an inbuilt method that allows you to find the number of elements in the array?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: this will already work, but you could do `b.length` to get the array size

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `b.length` to find out how many characters there are.

This is only the number of characters, not indexing, so if you iterate over it with a `for` loop, remember to write it like this:

```
for(int i=0;i < b.length; i++)
```

Note the `<` (not a `<=`).  It's also important to note that since the array isn't a class, .`length` isn't a function, so you shouldn't have parenthesis afterward.

Answer (score 18):

Don't listen to any of these guys, here, try this!

```
static int length(final char[] b) {
  int n = 0;
  while (true) {
    try {
      int t = b[n++];
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return n;
}
```

(Just kidding... try `b.length`.)

Answer (score 2):

`b.length` is the way to find length of array

`length` property determines size of the [array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Answer (score 0):

The above answers work. Also, if for some reason you need to know the array size before you actually create the array (for pre-processing or some such activity), you can get the string's length (which will be equal to that of the array).

```
inputString.length()
```

Comment: Since `b` is an array in this case, the parentheses will cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

Once an array is created, its size is fixed. It cannot be changed. You can find its size using `arrayRefVar.length`. For example, `myList.length` returns 10.

Answer (score 0):

b.length;  is very much handy and very much useful to find the length of char[] array:)